# Could not inflate Behavior subclass com.google.android.material.transition.MaterialContainerTransform

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml

So i'm using following a guide to implement fab transformation to a container. This was the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.material.circularreveal.CircularRevealFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sheet"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:background="@color/secondaryColor"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.transformation.FabTransformationSheetBehavior">
  
    </com.google.android.material.circularreveal.CircularRevealFrameLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

It works fine but

> FabTransformationSheetBehavior

is deprecated now. I googled and came up with this

> com.google.android.material.transition.MaterialContainerTransform

which should now be used instead of that. But when I replace it , I get a layout inflation error.

> Could not inflate Behavior subclass
> com.google.android.material.transition.MaterialContainerTransform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the MaterialContainerTransform cannot be used in layout_behavior attribute.

You need to create an instance of MaterialContainerTransform and initialize it with some parameters.

Here is an example which kind of worked for my case:

```
MaterialContainerTransform transform = new MaterialContainerTransform();
        transform.setStartView(your FAB goes here);
        transform.setEndView(view which you are transitioning to);
        transform.setPathMotion(new MaterialArcMotion()); //optional
        transform.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); //optional
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(container, transform);
```

Additionally, with this approach you don't actually need to stick to this kind of layout and specific hierarchy anymore.

Here is the link you can refer to learn more:
https://material.io/develop/android/theming/motion